# All combination of string char

Tags: java, recursion

I have string and i need to print all the combination of the string Char's
Example
For the string "123" the output is:
1,2,3,12,13,21,23,31,32,123,132,213,231,312,321
It must be without loops, only with recursion.
Thanks!

Comment: And what have you tried? This is not a code writing service. Show us what you have tried and what errors occurred. Sounds like a homework question anyway.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please take the [tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour), have a look around, and read through the [help center](http://stackoverflow.com/help), in particular [How do I ask a good question?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [What topics can I ask about here?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic). From that second link: "Questions asking for homework help must include a summary of the work you've done so far to solve the problem, and a description of the difficulty you are having solving it."

Comment: Once when I was a TA, I proposed to rename "*homework*" to "*yourwork*". Although the proposal did not make it, I think it is still in the spirit of what homework is supposed to mean.

Comment: You won't get far just asking people to code a solution for you. Stackoverflow is many things, but two it is not would be 1) a free coding service 2) A homework doer. If you need help writing software you should hire a freelance developer (which are not free). If you need help with your homework, talk to your teacher or get a tutor. Once you start coding, if you hit any issue THEN come post a question describing the exact issue

Answer (score 1):

```
public class CharacterRecursion
{
    private String str;
    private int counter;
    public CharacterRecursion()
    {
        str = "";
        counter = 0;
    }
    public CharacterRecursion(String str1)
    {
        str = str1;
        counter = 0;
    }
    public String recurse(String str)
    {
        if (counter == 15)
        {
            return ;
        }
        counter++;
        // return (recurse(String str _________) _________) _________;
    }
    public String [] toString()
    {
        String [] arr = new String[14];
        for (int i = 0; i < 14; i++)
        {
            arr[i] = this.recurse();
        }
        return arr;
    }
    public static void main(String [] args)
    {
        CharacterRecursion recurse = new CharacterRecursion("123")
        System.out.println(recurse.toString);
    }
}
```

I think just giving you the full code would be a little to easy for you. This is the simple set up for the code that you would want. The recurse method is not completely finished, the return statement being one of the things that you will need to fix first. By answer the question, this way, I hope that I am still answering the question, but also still allowing you to fully learn and understand recursion on your one. By the way,

for the public static void main(String [] args) part

You would also put that in a separate class like so:

```
public class CharacterRecursion
{
    private String str;
    private int counter;
    public CharacterRecursion()
    {
        str = "";
        counter = 0;
    }
    public CharacterRecursion(String str1)
    {
        str = str1;
        counter = 0;
    }
    public String recurse(String str)
    {
        if (counter == 15)
        {
            return ;
        }
        counter++;
        // return (recurse(String str _________) _________) _________;
    }
    public String [] toString()
    {
        String [] arr = new String[14];
        for (int i = 0; i < 14; i++)
        {
            arr[i] = this.recurse();
        }
        return arr;
    }


public class CharacterRecursionClient
{
    public static void main(String [] args)
    {
        CharacterRecursion recurse = new CharacterRecursion("123")
        System.out.println(recurse.toString);
    }
}
```

That would work just as well if you are required to have a client class. I hope that this help and cleared up at least a couple of things.